# %LIKE% replacement with CONTAINS

Tags: sql-server

We are changing our queries from:

```
SELECT * FROM {table} WHERE colname LIKE '%search term%'
```

to:

```
SELECT * FROM {table} WHERE CONTAINS(colname, '"search term"')
```

Unfortunately it does not seem to be 100% equivalent to "two way like".

If I use entire word "search term" it is fine and expected results are returned, but if I enter "earch ter" no results are returned. We also tried

```
SELECT * FROM {table} WHERE CONTAINS(colname, '"earch ter*"')
```

but it only works fine if I enter "search".

So is there any operator to `100% mimic %LIKE%` functionality with contains.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no 100% mimic `%LIKE%` operator in full-text search. More info you can find on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142583.aspx)  the part with **Supported Forms of Query Terms** title.

Comment: Thanks, I just thought that.